# Binding code behind variable not working

Tags: c#, data-binding

I have a `RequiredFieldValidator` on one of my DropDownLists in my user control. The `ErrorMessage` renders as `<%# areaType %> is required.`

```
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ID="areaRequiredFieldValidator" Display="None" ControlToValidate="area" EnableClientScript="False" ErrorMessage="<%# areaType %> is required."></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

Code behind...

```
private StateAreaDropDownEnums.AreaTypes _areaType;

protected string areaType {
    get { return _areaType.ToString(); }
}
```

I do `Page.DataBind()` in the `Page_Load` and all the other references to other code behind variables are binding just fine, only this one fails. Any ideas?

**NOTE**: This is a 3.5 website project, not a web app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ErrorMessage='<%=string.Format("{0} is required.", areaType)%>'>
```

should work. In this instance you are simply setting a value, not binding, so the binding syntax doesn't apply.

Comment: nope that wouldn't :) webforms distinguishes between single and double quotes. anytime you want to bind like this use single quotes. I updated my answer to reflect this.